# Connect nginx websocket with SSL ciphers

Tags: c, ssl, encryption, nginx, websocket

I deployed a nginx web service with below config

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name localhost;
    root html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/current.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/current.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://172.16.9.245:33400;
    }
    location /csconf/ {
            proxy_pass http://172.16.9.245:33200;
    }
    location /websockets/ {
            proxy_pass http://172.16.9.245:33143;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

My customer try to connect into this websocket using C code

```
.....
const SSL_METHOD *meth = SSLv3_method();
SslCtx = SSL_CTX_new(meth);
SSL_CTX_set_options(SslCtx, SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION);
SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(SslCtx, "RC4-SHA:DEC-CBC3-SHA:DES-CBC-SHA");
.....
int ret = SSL_connect(obj->ssl);
```

It throw "error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:741:"

Why the handshake error? Please help me to explain the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the reason, but it fixed the handshake error I was getting:

Change

`proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";`

To capital `Upgrade`

`proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";`